# ¿por que al usar un archivo JSON que mando en una función me da indefinido al usarlo?? en laravel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery, laravel

¿Qué tal?

tengo un problema al querer usar un archivo JSON.
pero antes...
tengo una vista, donde tengo un botón y una caja de texto para que el usuario ponga alguna clave, y posteriormente le de a agregar para que con la clave se pongan los datos del producto. algo asi se ve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve, si hace el trabajo, pero los trae como indefinidos.

el código lo tengo asi.

**función para retornar un JSON**

```
  public function datosProd(Request $request){
    $clave = $request->input('agregar');

    $producto=productos::where('claveProd',$clave)->first();  #productos es mi modelo
    
    if($producto){
        return response()->json([
        'clave'=>$producto->claveProd,
        'Grupo'=>$producto->Grupo,
        'Marca'=>$producto->Marca,
        'precio'=>$producto->Precio_vta
        ]);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

posterior a ello lo defino en mi archivo de rutas

**rutas web**

```
Route::post('/obtener', [VentasController::class, 'datosProd']);
```

**boton**

```
  <button class="ml-4 inline-block bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 text-black font-semibold rounded py-2 px-4"
            onclick="agregar()" value="">
            Agregar producto
        </button>
```

para comunicar el backend con el front uso JQuery

**código para agregar a la tabla**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>


<script>
function agregar() {
    var claveProducto = document.getElementById('agregar').value;
    var cantidadProducto=1;
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    // Realizar la petición AJAX al backend de Laravel para obtener el valor del producto
    $.ajax({
        url: '/obtener', //<-- definido en las rutas
        type: 'POST', //<-- tipo POST
        data: { //<-- aca mando lo que se va a usar en el backend
            claveProducto: claveProducto
        },

        success: function(response) {
            var valorProducto = response.precio;
            var Grupo = response.Grupo;
            var Marca = response.Marca;

            // Calcular el total
            var total = 1 * valorProducto;

            // Crear una nueva fila en la tabla con los valores obtenidos
            var tabla = document.getElementById('agregartb');
            var fila = tabla.insertRow();
            fila.innerHTML = '<td>' + claveProducto + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + Grupo + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + Marca + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + cantidadProducto + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + valorProducto + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + total + '</td>';
        }
    });
}
```

ustedes, que tienen más experiencia.

¿me podrían ayudar?

cualquier ayuda será bien recibida.

de antemano y adelantándome, muchas gracias. =)

Comment: Hola. No entiendo mucho cuál es el problema. ¿Hiciste un debug de `$producto` antes del `if`? ¿Hiciste un debug del JSON donde lo recibes? ¿Qué es lo que te da undefined exactamente? Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: Al igual que @A.Cedano... pienso que te falta hacer mas debug de tu parte. Pero a simple vista lo que veo es que en el post, en los datos envias un valor `claveProducto`, pero en el controlador usas el valor de `agregar`. Es decir, el valor enviado `claveProducto` no veo que lo estés usando. Ese supongo que es el problema. A propósito, es "raro" usar un POST para obtener información, porque no usar GET?